# How to propagate a promise error to a higher promise level after loading a file?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, promise, bluebird

I'm working on an async script loader using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) and I'm struggling to pass an error up to where I can catch it.

When a file is loaded I'm calling my method named `declare` like this:

```
  declare("storage", [
    {"name": 'util', "src": '../src/util.js'}
  ], function (util) {
    var storage = {};
    //...stuff with util
    return storage;
  });
```

With `declare` being:

```
declare = function (name, dependency_list, callback) {
   var resolver;

   // digest promises returned for each module
   function digestDependencyArray(my_dependency_array) {
     var i, len, response_array;

     len = my_dependency_array.length;
     for (i = 0, response_array = []; i < len; i += 1) {
       response_array[i] = my_dependency_array[i];
     }

     return Promise.all(response_array);
   }

   // resolve request promise
   function resolveDependencyArray(my_fullfillment_array) {
      var return_value = callback.apply(window, my_fullfillment_array);

      // window.exports must be used when integrating commonjs modules
      if (!return_value) {
        return_value = window.exports;
      }

      resolver(return_value);
   }

   // START: set callback to (resolved) callback or new promise
   my_lib.callback_dict[name] = my_lib.callback_dict[name] ||
      new Promise(function (resolve) {
        resolver = resolve;
        if (dependency_list.length === 0) {
          return resolver(callback.apply(window));
        }

        return request(dependency_list)
          .then(digestDependencyArray)
          .then(resolveDependencyArray)
          // DON'T CATCH HERE...
          .catch(console.log);
      });
  };
```

This all works fine except I would like to not have the `catch` statement at this point, because the error handling should be done in a different module (the console.log is just a flag).

**Question**:
How would I propagate an error occuring in my `declare` method to a higher promise chain? I had hoped adding a `catch` handler on my `declare` calls would help, but this breaks the whole script - I assume because I'm returning the module from my declare call vs a valid promise response.

Thanks for any tips!

**EDIT**:
I'm calling declare from this:

```
 request([{"name": "foo", "src": "path/to/foo.js"}])
   .spread(foo) {

 })
 .catch(function (e) {
   console.log(e);
 })
```

`request` will load the file inside a promise which gets resolved when the file is loaded and run the file content as callback, which then calls the above `declare` method. Somehow my error is lost on the way (code [here](https://github.com/frequent/clappjs/blob/master/src/clapp.loader.js)). Let's see if I can `catch` it somewhere...

**Edit 2**:
Changing to this inside declare:

```
function resolveDependencyArray(my_fullfillment_array) {
  var return_value = callback.apply(window, my_fullfillment_array);

  if (!return_value) {
    return_value = window.exports;
  }
  return return_value;
}

function handler() {
  if (dependency_list.length === 0) {
    Promise.resolve(callback.apply(window));
  } else {
    return request(dependency_list)
      .then(digestDependencyArray)
      .then(resolveDependencyArray)
      .catch(function (e) {
        reject(e);
      });
  }
}

clappjs.callback_dict[name] = clappjs.callback_dict[name] || handler();
```

While I get no errors, requesting multiple modules does not work because modules are returned `undefined`, so:

```
request(["foo", "bar", "baz"]).spread(function (foo, bar, baz) {
 console.log(foo);  // undefined
 console.log(bar);  // {} OK
 console.log(baz);  // undefined
});
```

versus a `new Promise` properly returning the file once it's loaded.

Comment: I guess you orginally wanted to do `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { … .catch(reject); }` However, that's an antipattern :-/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to rethrow the error!

```
.catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e); // calling it as a method, btw
  throw e;
})
```

You also might try to use [`tap`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#tapfunction-handler---promise), or return the promise that you have in the chain before adding `.catch(console.log)`.

---

Also, you are using the [manually-construct-promise antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern), while you actually should never need to [call the `Promise` constructor](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#new-promisefunctionfunction-resolve-function-reject-resolver---promise). Just use the promise that you already have! It seems that you want to do this:

```
my_lib.callback_dict[name] = my_lib.callback_dict[name] || (
  dependency_list.length === 0
  ? Promise.resolve()
  : request(dependency_list)
      .then(digestDependencyArray)
      .then(resolveDependencyArray) // don't call a global `resolver()`
                                    // just `return` the value!
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the anti-pattern example. One question regarding the throw: It seems I'm throwing, but I'm catching the error nowhere else. See my edit above.

Comment: Yeah, right, in the original code with the `Promise` constructor it's an unhandled rejection, as nothing happens with that promise. You'd need to call `reject(e)` instead of throwing. However, in the fixed code, the rejected promise is assigned to the `callback_dict`, from where it should propagate when that promise is `request()`ed. Or doesn't it work like that?

Comment: the reject solved it for me. I'm not sure I understand the snippet, because I set a `new` Promise per file I'm loading. If the file has been loaded before the Promise is resolved and the return value is given back (at `clappjs.callback_dict[name]`). If it needs to be loaded and has no dependencies, I can just set the new promise to resolved right away. If it has dependencies, those need to be loaded first and included in the eventual resolve. So I don't see why I can do this without a "new" Promise.

Comment: Yeah, somewhere you typically will want to create a `new Promise`, usually for loading the file. But not in this place, where you either create a fulfilled promise when there are no dependencies (`Promise.resolve()`) or you just *compose* the promise that `request()` returns to a new one by calling `.then()` on it. Don't use the `Promise` constructor here!

Comment: Tried again (see edit2 above), but I'm not getting good results, because some requested modules are returned `undefined`, while using my original code always returns the correct modules. I'm ok for now, will investigate if I have time and post a full example, too if you want to take another jab at it. Thanks so far!

Comment: In the case that you don't use the `new Promise` constructor, you should either omit (like in my second snippet) the catch or rethrow from it - there is no `reject()` you can call.

Answer (score 1):

Providing `request([])` returns `[]` and `callback` happily accepts `[]`, then `declare()` should simplify as follows :

```
declare = function(name, dependency_list, callback) {
    if(!my_lib.callback_dict[name]) {
        my_lib.callback_dict[name] = request(dependency_list).then(function(arr) {
            return Promise.all(arr);
        }).then(function(arr) {
            return callback.apply(window, arr) || window.exports;
        });
    }
    return my_lib.callback_dict[name];
};
```

Then make sure `callback` returns something falsy, eg `null` for condition(s) where `window.exports` should be used.

I may have made one or two involuntary assumptions, but I'm sure something close to the above should do the job.

Personally, I would handle any errors back in the call.

```
declare(name, dependency_list, callback).then(handleSucces).then(null, handleError);
```

By handling success and failure in separate `.then`s, any uncaught error thrown in `handleSuccess` will also be caught by `handleError`.